# nuspec contentFiles element invalid in metadata

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I have included the following in my nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <metadata minClientVersion="3.3">
        <contentFiles>
            <file src="*.css" target="_css" />
        </contentFiles>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

However, I get the following error:

> MSBUILD : OctoPack error OCTONUGET: The element 'metadata' in
>   namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'
>   has invalid child element 'contentFiles' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'. List of
>   possible elements expected: 'language, licenseUrl, projectUrl,
>   requireLicenseAcceptance, summary, tags, frameworkAssemblies, title,
>   references, copyright, authors, description, version, iconUrl, owners,
>   dependencies, id, developmentDependency, releaseNotes' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'.

When I look here: https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html, what I've done seems correct. What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There were two problems with this.

One was as per the 'BikerDude' answer.

The second that the target did not begin with

> lib, content, build, or tools

as per the documentation.

My final markup looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata minClientVersion="3.3">
        <id>Application Id</id>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <description>Solution description</description>
        <authors>Development Team</authors>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="\_css\**\*.*" target="content\_css" />
        <file src="\_scripts\**\*.*" target="content\_scripts" />
        <file src="\_images\**\*.*" target="content\_images" />
    </files>
</package>
```

I then created a virtual directory in IIS for the 'content' directory, so that the file references did not need to change.

Answer (score 1):

The NuSpec [file reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#specifying-files-to-include-in-the-package) indicates that `<Contentfile>` and `<File>` are two independent tags. You can't nest `<file>` under `<Contentfile>`

Use the following pattern:

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\*.dll" target="lib" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\*.pdb" target="lib" />
    <file src="tools\**\*.*" exclude="**\*.log" />
</files>
```

`<contentfiles>` is only supported NuGet 3.3+, maybe you have an older NuGet(NuGet 2.x or earlier)?